# Пуск/останов демона Git

Tags: git, ubuntu

На Ubuntu установлен Git. Нужно иногда отключать, а затем - включать его демон. Как это делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополню предыдущий ответ. Из [справки](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git) по установке и настойке Git для Ubuntu 9.10 и позже

```
sudo service git-daemon start/stop/restart/reload
```

Answer (score 3):

/etc/init.d/git-daemon start/stop?